# How to scale Heroku Django Celery app with Docker

Tags: django, docker, heroku, celery

I'm trying to deploy my Django app to Heroku and i have several doubts about dynos, workers and deploy configuration.

In my heroku.yml file I have 2 types of processes, one for the web and the other for celery, I would like them to both have only 1 dyno but with several workers and to be scalable if necessary.

heroky.yml:

```
build:
  docker:
  web: Dockerfile-django
  celery: Dockerfile-django
run:
  web: gunicorn project.wsgi --log-file -
  celery: celery -A project worker -B --loglevel=INFO
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  web:
    container_name: dilains_django_ctnr
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-django
    restart: always
    env_file: ./project/project/.env
    command: python manage.py check
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - ./project:/dilains
    depends_on:
      - postgres
      - redis
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    networks:
      - dilains-ntwk
  redis:
    container_name: dilains_redis_ctnr
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-redis
    volumes:
      - ./redis-data:/data
    ports:
      - 3679:3679
    networks:
      - dilains-ntwk
  celery:
    container_name: dilains_celery_ctnr
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-django
    restart: always
    env_file: ./project/project/.env
    command: celery -A project worker -B --loglevel=INFO
    volumes:
      - ./project:/dilains
    depends_on:
      - redis
      - web
      - postgres
    networks:
      - dilains-ntwk

networks:
  dilains-ntwk:
    driver: bridge
```

Dockerfile-django:

```
FROM python:3.7-alpine
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN apk update && apk add --no-cache bash postgresql postgresql-dev gcc python3-dev musl-dev jpeg-dev zlib-dev libjpeg
RUN mkdir /dilains
COPY ./project /dilains/
COPY ./requirements.txt /dilains/
WORKDIR /dilains
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 8000
```

I tried scale with this commands to scale each process type with 4 workers:

```
$ heroku ps -a app_name
=== celery (Standard-1X): /bin/sh -c celery\ -A\ project\ worker\ -B\ --loglevel\=INFO (1)
celery.1: up 2020/10/23 08:05:31 +0200 (~ 41m ago)
=== web (Standard-1X): /bin/sh -c gunicorn\ project.wsgi\ --log-file\ - (1)
web.1: up 2020/10/23 08:05:40 +0200 (~ 41m ago)

$ heroku ps:scale web=1 worker=4 -a app_name 
$ heroku ps:scale celery=1 worker=4 -a app_name
```

I'm paying Stardar-1X and tells: number of process type - unlimited and horizontally scaling - yes

Anybody could help please ?